# in PHP what is the difference if i use ./ (dot slash) when calling a file compared to not using it

Tags: php, include, directory

would it affect the performance of the application if i use ./ when calling a class file in php or on any programming language.

example is: include "./includes/functions.php";

against: include "includes/functions.php";

Comment: ofcourse not, that is just the path you are declaring.

Answer (score 4):

**Write what you mean.**

`./foo` means *`foo` in the current directory*.
`foo` means *`foo` in the current or any directory in [the include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)*.

It's an important difference in *meaning*, performance is irrelevant and negligible. If `foo` exists in the current directory, there'll be no difference.

Comment: I realise the OP asked for performance details, but for me this explanation hits the important spot: **`./` does not search in the include path.**

Answer (score 2):

php docs on [`include`](http://php.net/include):

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

in the [description of core php.ini directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) it is mentioned, that

> Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

but then again, you don't call `include` that often. performance overhead is negligible and not critical for your application. as Knuth has put it: »premature optimization is the root of all evil«

Answer (score 0):

There will be an insignificant speed difference due to the length of the string that you are using. In terms of style, using "./" implies that you intentionally mean a relative filename and have not just missed the leading slash out accidentally.

Comment: I agree that using `./` is kind of programming safety as you intentionally mean relative path and did not forget anything. For readability and code maintance I suggest going with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much of a difference. Both produce de same opcode, and the path resolution is done within a well optimised C function in the PHP core or within a (very) well optimised C system call. Even if there is a difference it won't affect your overall performances since you rarely `require` hundreds of thousands of files…

EDIT: i've just run some test (including 10,000 files), and there is absolutely no difference, except that:

- `./libdir/file.php` will look for the
  file in the current folder
- `libdir/file.php` will look for the
  file in the current folder and in the
  $PATH

Answer (score -1):

Both mean the same. If there is a differenece in PHP file IO system parsing it then it should be totally minimal and only be visible in large benchmarks. You can try that but I doubt that the difference would be significant.

Comment: See @deceze his answer for why this answer is not factually correct. There is a **very** important difference (the include path).